# Alterar versão do SDK 3.1 to 2.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Fiz toda minha API ASPNET Core 3.1 mas quando eu fui configurar o CICD, o NuGet Restore acusa erro de versão... Falando que tenho que usar uma versão 2.1 ou menor. (erro a seguir)

> '##[error]The nuget command failed with exit code(1) and
> error(C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.515\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets(137,5):
> error NETSDK1045: The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET
> Core 3.1.  Either target .NET Core 2.1 or lower, or use a version of
> the .NET SDK that supports .NET Core 3.1.'

Pelo que pesquisei, eu preciso ir no projeto -> propriedades e alterar a versão:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém quando eu faço isso, a minha classe startup.cs acusa erros:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

e

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguem sabe me confirmar se essa é mesma a forma certa ou falta eu fazer alguma coisa?

obrigado desde já.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existe [um post no StackOverflow original](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55741953/getting-netsdk1045-the-current-net-sdk-does-not-support-net-core-3-0-as-a-tar) que detalha todas as possíveis causas deste comportamento. Em tradução literal:

> Esses dias, eu tive que superar esse problema em várias
> máquinas/*containers* de desenvolvimento diferentes: finalmente,
> encontrei nada menos que 6 razões diferentes que poderiam causar esse
> tipo de erro:
>
> - SDK do .NET Core 3 ausente (x86 ou x64) Suporte à visualização do .NET
> - Core SDK não ativado no VS2019 VS2017 em vez de VS2019 Caminho
> - Caminho incorreto do SDK nas variáveis ​​de ambiente PATH
> - Caminho incorreto do SDK nas variáveis ​​de ambiente MSBuildSDKsPath
> - Caminho incorreto do SDK no arquivo global.json do projeto
>
> As soluções alternativas para
> esses cenários são bastante fáceis de entender, você basicamente
> precisa instalar o SDK adequado ou remover as referências "ofensivas"
> do SDK. No entanto, fiz o possível para documentá-los todos [neste post](https://www.ryadel.com/en/current-net-sdk-not-support-net-core-3-0-fix/) no meu blog. *(n.t.: blog em inglês.)*

Em resumo: Ao invés de refatorar seu código para 2.1 (que é uma versão intersticial), [instale o .NET Core 3 SDK](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/3.1).

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. O problema não é em si na minha maquina. Funciona perfeitamente. Tenho o SDK 3 na minha maquina... O problema é no portal devops quando vai rodar o pipe pro CI...

Comment: @LucasBersot talvez este post lhe ajude então: "Setting up Azure DevOps CI/CD for a .NET Core 3.1 Web App hosted in Azure App Service for Linux" - https://www.hanselman.com/blog/SettingUpAzureDevOpsCICDForANETCore31WebAppHostedInAzureAppServiceForLinux.aspx